# Получение id динамически созданных кнопок в LinearLayout

Tags: android

Есть `LinearLayout`. В коде создаю 10 кнопок и добавляю их на `LinearLayout`. На каждую кнопку ставлю контекстное меню, при долгом нажатии на кнопку создается диалог, в котором 2 варианта: переименовать и удалить кнопку.

Я не могу понять как получить id кнопки, на которую я нажал. Чтобы текст менялся именно на ней и удалялась именно та кнопка, которую я выбрал.

2 примера кода. В одном заполняю `LinearLayout`, а в другом хочу получить id той кнопки, на которую нажал. Пробовал через `linearLayout.getChildAt`, но там удаляется и переименовывается только тот элемент, индекс которого я укажу, а не тот, на который нажал.

Заполнение:

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("new button " + i);
    button.setId(i);
    registerForContextMenu(button);
    linearLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Обработка:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    final View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog, null);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuRename:
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Rename")
                    .setView(customView)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            EditText editText = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                            String nameButton = editText.getText().toString();
                            Button button = (Button) linearLayout.getChildAt(2);
                            button.setText(nameButton);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.menuDelete:
            linearLayout.removeView(linearLayout.getChildAt(2));
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте интовое поле в класс и сохраняйте туда ид вьюхи получаемой в `onCreateContextMenu`, ну и используйте его в вашем `onClick`.